# Geolocation not runs in Android

Tags: javascript, android, geolocation

When I run my code on Android device, the `getCurrentPosition` of the Geolocation API returns the `PERMISSION_DENIED` error code.

The same code is running in a Windows10 Mobile device (Edge), and on a Windows10 laptop (Edge, Mozilla, Chrome (57)).

Additionally the code is running on the Android if I copy it in the TryIt Editor v3.3 of the w3schools.com.

Any suggestion?

My  code is:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
<body>
  <p>  Hello, world!  </p>

<p> ------------------------</p>
<p> <img src="file:///D:/pictures/camera roll/WP_20170410_16_51_40_Pro.jpg" height="150px" width="250px" alt="image not found"/> </p>

<p> ------------------------</p>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>
​
<button onclick="getLocation()">Agree</button>
​
<p id="demo"></p>
​ 

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}


function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And you're running it from where? [Geolocation now requires SSL](https://mobiforge.com/news-comment/no-https-then-bye-bye-geolocation-in-chrome-50) or localhost etc (secure origin).

Comment: Is this running inside a webview by any chance? Also, try and add an if-else statement to see what navigator agent is running, to get what you want.

Comment: fixed some grammar and formatting

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. The problem isn't appears when I call the file (full path) from the browser address line (like file:///storage/emulated/12/Documents/test7.html). The problem stils when i try to open the file using the Android utility "Open With".